# Developing a scheduled task for Windows

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

I have to develop an application using C#.net that has to be run once a day. It only runs for at most one minute, so developing a Windows service is overkill and a scheduled task is the appropriate way.

However, I have a few questions about how the application can communicate its results:

- How do I indicate to the task scheduler that the task has failed? Is this via the program's exit code?
- How do I log output information? Is console output automatically captured or do I have to write to the event viewer explicitly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In answer to your questions -

1. If a task fails because it threw an unchecked exception you'll see that in the Sheduled Task viewer, there will be a 'Last Result' with a value something like `0xe0434f4d`. Alternatively if you return an exit code that will be also be shown in the Last Result column of the Scheduled Task viewer.
2. Writing to the console e.g. `Console.WriteLine("blah");` won't show up anywhere. You'd need to write to the event log or to a log file.

Answer (score 4):

If you go the *Log File* way, you can still use `Console.WriteLine("blah");`. The trick is to redirect the standard *Out* and *Error* streams:

```
        StreamWriter mylog = new StreamWriter("mylog.log");
        Console.SetOut(mylog);
        Console.SetError(mylog);
```

You also need to flush the buffers often, to make sure the log file contains current information.

```
            Console.Out.Flush();
```

This is quick and dirty, you really should use the *Windows Event Log* or  [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the scheduler just kicks off a process. You can use the event log or another logging system to record the information you need to refer to later.

Answer (score 0):

[Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a very good, complete logging framework. I can highly recommend it.