# Scheduled Task not triggering exe on windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, console-application, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a console application,whose target version is .Net Framework 3.5. When I try to trigger the complied exe manually, the program executes and does its job perfectly. But the exe is not at all getting triggered when using a Task Scheduler.

The error details in Task Sceduler is as follows:

**last run result 0xE0434F4D**

**Edits:**

The event log is as follows,

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: flvtomp4converter.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 4ffa8abc
P4: mscorlib
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 4e1539fa
P7: 349e
P8: 119
P9: System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
P10:
```

What is happening here?

Comment: The fact that there is an error means it is running, but is failing. It's probably a rights issue (when **you** run it, it can do what you can do, when the **scheduler** runs it, it'll probably run as a more restricted user). Add debugging output to your program to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: What does the windows event log say? There's probably a .net exception hiding in there somewhere. It's going to be a whole bunch more useful than an error code.

Comment: You should (or did you?) try to google for "last run result 0xE0434F4D", you'd find among others, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/173462/21567).

Comment: Spender: I ve added the event log information. IF its an exception, then why would the application run without any problem when I am manually running the exe?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to wonderful world of Windows 2008 family.
This is about under what user your application scheduled to run in Task Scheduler and what permission that specific user have to all(!!!) folders involved in processing by your application.
Also you must make sure that this user authorized to run batch processes in security settings.
Just been member of administrators group no longer is enough!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because my console app trying to create an `log.txt` file inside `C:\Windows\System32` and the task scheduler has no permission to create a new file inside that folder.

This is happen because i don't specify an absolute filename where to put the log file.

---

Let me explain this with an example of my code :

I have a program inside this directory `D:\somefolder\` and the `.exe` directory is `D:\somefolder\program.exe`

This is a snapshot of my code (visual basic)

Wrong :

```
Dim logFileName As String = "log.txt"
/*
     Create file based on logFileName directory 
*/
```

- If I execute `.exe` via windows explorer -> it'll create a log file with directory `D:\somefolder\log.txt` **(no problem)**
- If I execute `.exe` via task scheduler -> it'll create a log file with directory `C:\Windows\System32\log.txt` **(This will leave last run result 0xE0434F4D**)

Correct :

```
Dim logFileName As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/log.txt"
/*
     Create file based on logFileName directory 
*/
```

- If I execute `.exe` via windows explorer -> it'll create a log file with directory `D:\somefolder\log.txt` **(no problem)**
- If I execute `.exe` via task scheduler -> it'll create a log file with directory `D:\somefolder\log.txt` **(no problem)**

So you need to specify an absolute filename where to put the log file. In my example I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`